# Парсинг необязательного параметра

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть конструкция которая парсит команду `/start` в телеграм боте c параметрами.

```
$command = '/start 123';
$regex = '/(\/start\s)(\d+)/';
if(preg_match($regex, $command, $match)) {
    echo 'start with parameter detected';
}
```

Как в регулярном выражении указать, что `(\d+)` опциональный параметр?
Что бы можно было отлавливать как `/start` так и `/start 123`?

Comment: Использовать ленивый квантификатор (`?`) после группы с числом, регулярное выражение может иметь следующий вид: [`\/start\s(\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/KRkBCG/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте квантификатор `?` следующим образом:

```
$regex = '/(\/start)(?:\s(\d+))?/';
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/OvKIyM/1).

- `(\/start)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: `/start`
- `(?:` - начало необязательной незахватывающей подмаски (так как после неё сразу стоит квантификатор `?`)

  - `\s` - пробельный символ
  - `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: 1 и более цифр
- `)?` - конец необязательной незахватывающей подмаски, 1 или 0 повторов.